# Как нарисовать дугу по трём точкам с помощью d3?

Tags: svg, d3.js

У меня есть три точки (`x1,y1, x2,y2, x3,у3`). Как с помощью `d3` нарисовать дугу?

Пробовал по 2 точкам и радиусу, результат не устраивает:

```
const path = d3.path();

path.moveTo(100, 200);
path.arcTo(100, 150, 150, 150, 150);

svg.append("path")
  .attr("d", path.toString())
  .attr("stroke", "firebrick")
  .attr("stroke-width", 2)
  .attr("fill", "none");
```

** Дуга должна стремится к прямой линии при большом радиусе.*

Comment: Попробуйте посмотреть решение тут https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43825414/draw-an-svg-arc-using-d3-knowing-3-points-on-the-arc

Comment: @Denis640Kb спасибо)! Но гуглить я умею. Необходимо на `d3`.

Comment: @СвободуСергеюСуровцеву так а на d3 и не на d3 смысл один, нужно посчитать радиус и направление дуги